# A question about support

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Since the support of a function between Euclidean spaces is defined as
$$\mbox{supp}(v) = \overline{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n; \ v(x) \neq 0\}},$$
we can conclude, for example, that if $x \not\in \mbox{supp}(v)$, then $v(x) = 0$.

However, my question is the following:

If $v \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $v(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus X$, then we can conclude that $ \mbox{supp}(v) \subset X$?

Comment: if $X$ is closed

Comment: Example with a $C^\infty$ function: $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x\ne0$ and $f(0)=0$. Take $X=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ and note that $\operatorname{supp}(f)=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: or analytic function $f(x) = x$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\text{supp}(f) = \mathbb{R}$ and take $X = \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, we cannot.

Take $n=1$, $X=(0,\infty)$ and$$v(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x<0\\x^2&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then $(\forall x\in\Bbb R\setminus X):v(x)=0$. However, $\operatorname{supp}(v)\not\subset X$, since $\operatorname{supp}(v)=[0,\infty)$.